# Xamarin.Forms dynamic button styling

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-styles

I'd like to implement my own custom button style. The style has to change, whenever the button changes his state (from enabled to disabled i.e.).

My current solution is to define a style in Android and my custom ButtonRenderer applies this style to the button.

**Button_Style.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#d7d7d7" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#d7d7d7" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#efefef" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#efefef" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#d7d7d7"
          android:endColor="#d7d7d7"
          android:angle="270" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#d7d7d7" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

**custom Renderer:**

```
using FrameworkForms.UserControl;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Color = Android.Graphics.Color;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(FrameworkForms.Droid.Renderer.CustomizedButtonRenderer))]
namespace FrameworkForms.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class CustomizedButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.button_style);
                Control.SetAllCaps(false);
                if (!Control.Enabled)
                {
                    Control.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#858585"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a binding on my buttons enabled property. The problem is pretty obvious, once the property changes, the button doesn't get renderered again and keeps the textcolor of the previous state.

I've done a little research about styles in Xamarin.Forms. It seems like dynamic styling should do it for me, but I'd like to have it for all my buttons (like a global style). Can I somehow combine them? Or is this even a better solution? Worth mentioning, I don't mind implementing the whole thing for iOS again. It's gonna be different anyways. So Android xml-Styles will do it too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change something when the `IsEnabled` property changes, then you need to override `OnElementPropertyChanged`:

```
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if(e.PropertyName == "IsEnabled")
        {
            if(Element.IsEnabled)
            {
                Control.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#858585"));
                Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.YourEnabledResource);
            }
            else
            {
                Control.SetTextColor(Element.TextColor.ToAndroid());
                Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.YourDisabledResource);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can create two drawable xml files to define your different resources for enabled and disabled. I titled them `YourEnabledResource` and `YourDisabledResource` accordingly.

Comment: That's not the problem. The binding is working correctly and the background of the button gets set.

Comment: This is your problem. I used the `SetTextColor` as an example. The point is still the same. When the `IsEnabled` property is changed, it fires here, if you need to change your background resource, you can do that here too. I'll edit my answer to be more clear...

Comment: Also, the answer directly respondes to this: "The problem is pretty obvious, once the property changes, the button doesn't get renderered again and keeps the textcolor of the previous state.".... This will change the text color when you change the `IsEnabled` property. That's the whole point.

Comment: To be *extra* clear, you should override `OnElementChanged` the way you do now, but ALSO override `OnElementPropertyChanged`. This method will fire whenever you change the value of any of the bindable properties on your Xamarin.Forms Element.

Comment: I wasn't really reading your answer sorry. Of course that's it thank you :-)